# Mount remote port number

Tags: linux, mount, port

When I use this command:

```
mount remoteServerA:/pathInServer localpath
```

Which ports it use?

I don't know the type of the server (I guess it Linux server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mount` command with network drives will use NFS by default, which runs on ports 111 and 2049, but can also use additional ports in some configurations. See [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/377170/which-ports-do-i-need-to-open-in-the-firewall-to-use-nfs) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it not help to my case. I will post another question.

Comment: Can you help me in the next question?
http://superuser.com/questions/1152453/remote-mount-with-tunnel

Comment: If I turn the option - o tcp. It will be the same ports?