# Remote mount with tunnel

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, ssh-tunnel

When I log to ServerA with ssh, I have ping to ServerB.

If I had a sudo privilege on ServerA I would able to do this command:

```
sudo mount ServerB:/pathInServerB localPathServerA
```

I want to be able to mount directly to local machine from ServerB through ServerA.

1. I cannot ssh to ServerB. (so sshfs  with tunnel will not work in
   this case, I guess).
2. I can log in with ssh to serverA.
3. I don't have sudo privilege on server A.
4. I do have sudo privilege on local machine.

I already do the following:

- I ask this question: [Mount remote port number](https://superuser.com/questions/1152444/mount-remote-port-number/1152451#1152451)
- I do the following commands:

Code:

```
sudo ssh -f userName@ServerA -L 111:ServerB:111 -L 2049:ServerB:2049 -L 1110:ServerB:1110 -L 4045:ServerB:4045 -N
sudo mount -o tcp localhost:/PathInServerB localPath
```

I didn't succeeded.

How I do it?

Comment: ask sysadmin of serverA or serverB.

Comment: why sys admins? I sure I can remote mount with tunnel without them.

Comment: If you are talking nfs mount, they're default refuses any connection from ports above > 1024, and without root you cannot bind lower.

Comment: I have root on local

Comment: be happy then...

Comment: @IporSircer  I already bind port  111 from serverB to my local machine.
with this command:      
sudo ssh -f userName@ServerA -L 111:ServerB:111 -N

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49521/discussion-between-tal-and-ipor-sircer).

Comment: According to [this](http://serverfault.com/q/377170) and [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-nfs-firewall-config.html) NFS also uses UDP. SSH tunnels TCP, not UDP. I guess it may be the reason your approach failed. Not sure though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I can also do a mount tcp according to [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/System_Administration_Guide/s1-nfs-mount.html).
Change the command. please check the modified post.

Comment: If you don't need NFS, you could just use sshfs which operates all in user space and avoids all kinds of security issues, IMO.